# Interpreted language in Java and calls to Java methods

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection, interpreted-language

I have implemented simple interpreted language with dynamic typing in Java. Unfortunately I ran into the following problem. When testing the following code:

```
def main() {
    def ks = Map[[1, 2]].keySet();
    return ks.size();
}
```

I stumbled upon the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class is not public: java.util.HashMap$KeySet.size()int/invokeSpecial
```

Of course This is true and caused by the fact that HashMap$KeySet class has "package" visibility. This means that when I call it's "size()" method, I call method from class that is not visible to my code. Java avoids this problem easily - method keySet() returns value of type Set, so method size() used is declared in public and abstract class "Set".

My question is: does anyone has an idea, how this should be handled in generic way? By "general" case I mean not only this simple case, where I can walk through whole inheritance chain and find "first declaration" of this method, but also pathological cases like the following:

```
interface I1 {
    public void foo();
}
interface I2 {
    public void foo();
}
interface I3 {
    public void foo();
}
class C implements I1, I2, I3 {
    public void foo() { .... }
}
```

My current impression is that I could ignore those pathological cases and select any matching method on the grounds that if such object exists, then it's creation was successful, so it's compilation was successful, so all these methods have identical signatures and since in Java there is no way to specify different implementations of these methods depending on how object is viewed (as I1, I2 or I3), then result will be always the same.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should probably try to emulate the Java method resolution rules, except you would be doing it at runtime rather than compile time. Basically you'd have to look at the first method in the inheritance tree (the one closest to the root), and if there are multiple ones, choose the one that comes from a superclass. If they all come from interfaces, you can choose one arbitrarily.

Comment: A related question though is how all this would work with default methods.

Comment: Maybe it's not clear from my post, but this is precisely what I'm currently implementing, I'm simply not certain if this is THE solution. Maybe there is some better way, which is why I asked. Of course I could simply leave it as it is, since dynamic typing is only a phase for this project as I aim for static typing with type deduction, but leaving it with such a gaping hole is not something that I can do with clear conscience.

Comment: I agree, it does look ugly. And it gets a lot uglier when the method to be matched has arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here is my solution. It isn't very nice, but hey, whatever works:

```
    public static Method findMethod(Class<?> cls, String name, Class<?>[] fa) {
    System.out.println("Checking class " + cls + " for method " + name);
    // since it is called recursively, we want to stop some day, and when we are
    // passed null (so most getSuperclass was called on Object.class or something similar)
    if (cls == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Method m = null;
    if ((m = findMethod(cls.getSuperclass(), name, fa)) != null) {
        return m;
    }
    // ok, if we're here, then m is null. so check if cls is public. it must be public, because
    // otherwise we won't be able to call it - we are definitely in different package. if class
    // isn't public, then check interfaces.
    if (!Modifier.isPublic(cls.getModifiers())) {
        System.out.println("Class is not public, and superclasses do not contain method " + name);
        System.out.println("Checking all interfaces");
        for (Class<?> iface: cls.getInterfaces()) {
            if ((m = findMethod(iface, name, fa)) != null) {
                return m;
            }
        }
    }
    return findMethodInClass(cls, name, fa);
}
private static Method findMethodInClass(Class<?> cls, String name, Class<?>[] fa) {
    Method m = null;
    // scan all methods and move plausible candidates to the start of an array
    Method[] mm = cls.getMethods(); 
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < mm.length ; ++i) {
        if (checkMethod(mm[i], name, fa)) {
            mm[n++] = mm[i];
        }
    }
    if (n > 1) {
        System.out.println("Caveat: we have to perform more specific test. n == " + n);
        System.out.println("class: " + cls + "\nname: " + name);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i) {
            System.out.println(mm[i]);
        }
    }
    if (n > 0) {
        m = mm[0];
    }
    return m;
}
```

Method checkMethod() called in findMethodInClass simply checks if name is correct and if arguments with which method will be called more or less match formal argument list. It's implementation is left as a simple exercise for the reader. Any comments?